# PDF parsing with image coordinates

Tags: pdf-extraction

I have the PDF file with the images and texts. (set of instruction how to do things)

I'm able to parse and extract the text and image separately, but I'm not able to get the image represent in the PDF

I want to extract the PDF like there should be a word "figure" that represent the image place in the text where in the extracted text. i hope below will be clear you my logic.

**example: **

Level

• explain how a level signal is derived for: an open vessel, a
closed vessel with dry reference leg, a closed vessel with wet
reference leg;
*[consider there is image present here resenting the above point]*

• explain how a DP cell can be damaged from over pressure if it
is not isolated correctly;
*[consider there is image present here resenting the above point]
*

**Output should be like:**
Level
explain how a level signal is derived for: an open vessel, a
closed vessel with dry reference leg, a closed vessel with wet
reference leg;
Figure
explain how a DP cell can be damaged from over pressure if it
is not isolated correctly;
Figure